# How to use IN operator in SQL for a dynamically generated string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below mentioned is the sample code under discussion:

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE AS DATETIME
DECLARE @TODATE AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DAYS AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @FROMDATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-03')
SET @TODATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-06')

SET @DAYS = '''SUNDAY'',''MONDAY'',''TUESDAY'',''WEDNESDAY'',''FRIDAY'',''SATURDAY'''

PRINT @DAYS 
--(O/P - 'SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY')

SELECT 
    UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))), 
    * 
FROM 
    SQLTABLE
WHERE 
    UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))) IN (@DAYS)
```

If I pass values manually as below I get output:

```
UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))) 
IN ('SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY')
```

If I pass values using variable having the same values as shown in the O/P of `PRINT @DAYS` the result is blank:

```
UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))) 
IN (@DAYS)
```

Assuming that in actual scenario I am generating the values under `@DAYS` variable dynamically or passing it through code to the query / stored procedure below is my question :

Is it not allowed in SQL or am I doing it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute it as dynamic sql:

```
Set @sql='SELECT ... from ...  WHERE ... NOT IN ('+@days+')'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

If not, the whole param value will be considered as one value.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator is expecting a list of values separated by commas, but what you are providing it is a single value that contains a comma separated list.

You can solve it using dynamic SQL, as sagi suggested in his answer, or use a string split function ([in SQL Server 2016 it comes built in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)) to convert the single comma separated variable to a table -

```
SET @DAYS = 'SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY'

SELECT UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))), * 
FROM SQLTABLE
WHERE UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))) IN (STRING_SPLIT(@DAYS, ','))
```

If you are using a lower version then 2016, you need to create the string split user defined function yourself - or choose one from Aaron Bertrand's Split [strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

However, if your client supports it, I would suggest sending a table valued parameter to the database instead of dealing with comma delimited strings at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a fan of dynamic queries, this is an alternate approach to sagi's answer. You can create a table and populate the days you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #Days (NAME VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Days
VALUES ('SUNDAY'),('MONDAY'),('TUESDAY'),('WEDNESDAY'),('FRIDAY'),('SATURDAY')
```

and then inner join it with your table:

```
SELECT UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))),*
FROM SQLTABLE s
INNER JOIN #Days d ON d.NAME 
          = UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.APPDATE, 112))))
```

If you're using SQL Server 2016+, There is a [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function which returns a table with a `value` column.

```
SET @DAYS = 'SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY'

SELECT UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), APPDATE, 112)))), *
FROM SQLTABLE s
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@DAYS, ',') d ON d.value 
        = UPPER(DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.APPDATE, 112))))
```

(PS: [Zohar Peled's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022050/3082296) of `STRING_SPLIT` is better if you're using SQL Server 2016+)